# Tesseract training data

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

After hours of trial and error I have finally generated my training data for a font that I am trying to read.
I am trying to decode a captcha that has gone through preprocessing using OpenCV and currently trying to train Tesseract to read the font.

I have the training image:

[image]

where the image they were extracted from consist of a ton of preprocessed images like so:

[image]

While still being inaccurate with my current traindata that I generated after hours of searching, I was unable to find enough info about how to actually train tesseract. Am I able to add more than one box for the same letter? Such as having two capital A.. etc.. (10 sets of the alphabet and numbers) to help make the OCR more accurate?

EDIT: I have been using tesseract v3.05dev on windows OS

EDIT2: I have already made the box files for each letter/digit the box the actual size of each letter. (I am also not sure if I am suppose to leave some space within the box or not)